# How to start a new static website project with SASS installed in MACOS

Tags: sass, compass-sass

I was trying to install sass in one of my latest static website project, But got up with a few errors like FAILED TO BUILD GEM NATIVE EXTENSIONS. Its been 5 years I used sass last time, that time it was quite easy by simply adding gem install sass, But I found its difficult.

I have read a few articles and there its saying to install brew, RVM etc etc. I use MACOS. How can I solve my problem from scratch? What should I install and where to install (root / inside project folder).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ruby-sass` has been deprecated, and it's recommended that you use another installation method.
https://sass-lang.com/install

I recommend installing via brew (which is a package manager for OS X) since you're on OS X.
https://brew.sh/

To install Brew, open your terminal and paste this:

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

Once the install completes, enter the following command:

```
brew install sass/sass/sass
```

Comment: Thanks Buddy. Great Help!!

Comment: Appreciate the heads up ruby-sass is depreciated—using brew took only a few minutes.